# Laravel add query parameter to view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I return a view in my controller:

```
return view('leaderboard');
```

I would like to add query parameters to the response. So the url should change to https://site.test?stand=true

How can I do this? This is obviously not working:

```
   return view('leaderboard', ['stand' => true]);
```

And when I try this:

```
return redirect()->route('leaderboard', ['stand' => true]);
```

I get a infinite redirect. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: It seems you would like to set variable for view. correct?

Comment: Nope, I want to return the view and in the url should be `stand=true`.

Comment: this is because you are redirecting to the same route. controller method will execute and then redirect and again redirect ... I would suggest add route param in route. add your route code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are getting redirected on the same action again and again. You can add condition to verify if query params exists in URL then render view else redirect.

**Like:**

```
if (!$request->has('stand')) {
    return redirect()->route('leaderboard', ['stand' => true]);
}

return view('leaderboard');
```

Comment: @Jenssen let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a named route and want to redirect to url with params:

```
route('route', ['foo' => 'baz', 'bar' => 'foo']);
```

if you want to append to url

```
url('path') . '?' . http_build_query(['foo' => 'baz', 'bar' => 'foo']);
```

In order to redirect pass route as argument.

```
redirect(route('name', [...]))
```